# question about Fork()

Tags: c, process, fork

When a parent process creates a child process with `fork()`, according to me,
the child process is in a `Running` state whereas the parent process is in a `Ready` state, i.e. waiting for the child to end.

Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something from

> After a  fork(), it is indeterminate
>   which process—the parent or the
>   child—next has access to the CPU.
>
> Applications that implicitly or
>   explicitly rely on a particular
>   sequence of execution in order to
>   achieve correct results are open to
>   failure due to race conditions.

It goes on to point different behaviors in different kernels. The bottom line is that it's implementation-defined and not to be relied upon.

Also if you *do* want to rely on it, on Linux since 2.6.32 "there's a `sysctl` for that"

```
kernel.sched_child_runs_first
```

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

No, the fork creates a copy of the parent.

Then you generally tests for the return value of fork which says 0 = I am the child, other: I'm the parent and the child has the return value as PID

If the parent has to wait for the child to end, you need to use the wait function.

**Edit**:

see http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork and http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait for the fork() in C.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. On a sheduler level, these two processes can't have the Running state, so one is Running, the other is Ready ?

Comment: Depends on what the process is doing. But indeed, if your processor runs only one process at a time, the other can't be running as well (meaning it's something else that might be Ready state)

Comment: Logically and theoretically , child processus is Running and the parent is Ready (waiting for the end of child to become Running) ? thanks !

Comment: The parent does not wait for anything unless told for as I said in the post. So it depends of your context. Example, in a CLI environnement, if you don't use & parent is waiting, but with fork() the parent can still continue in execution while its son is running. They  will just share the processor depending on how the scheduler assign them to it.

Comment: On a single CPU only one process can be "Running" at the same time, but "Ready" means it's not waiting for anything but its next timeslice. I think this is where the misunderstanding comes from.